# _CastError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast) trying to read data fron json file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flutter, user-interface, native

this is my modal

```
class CelebDataModal {
  String ? name;
  String? image;
  
   CelebDataModal (
     this.name,
     this.image
   );
   CelebDataModal.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
     name = json["name"]  ;
     image = json["image"];
   }
     
}
```

trying to get data from json file

```
Future<List<CelebDataModal>> readJsonData() async{
      final jsondata = await rootBundle.loadString('jsonfile/data.json');
     final list = json.decode(jsondata)  as List<dynamic>;
      return   list.map((e) => CelebDataModal.fromJson(e)).toList();

    
  }
}
   _
```

> CastError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a
> subtype of type 'List' in type cast)

what could be the reason?

Comment: please share your json file, otherwise it's hard to judge your code.

Comment: And, if possible, provide more details at which position the problem occurs.

Comment: json code please